# Flexbox Header Footer Sidebar

Tags: css, flexbox

How can we make something like this using flexbox?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you understand this example of mine, then you understand the most important things about flexbox. This is the HTML markup

```
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebar firestarter">sidebar</div>
<div class="extraWrap">
<div class="header firestarter">
  <p><b>header</b>
</div>
<div class="xyz firestarter" id="x">
  <p>
    this your red div
  </p>
</div>
<div class="x firestarter" <p>
  this your grey div
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer firestarter">
  <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Here the link to the pen, where you can check the css and play around with the values:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmxmQE

I have added an animation on hover to to all sections.

This will be responsive and can easily be modified to any other layout for mobile devices, but do not rely on flexbox cross browser, the usability leaves plenty to be desired.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check out the pen

Comment: Welcome, also resize page to add height and see how the divs align in height

Comment: That's perfect man. Thank you very much. Though I am not understanding about a few things. What did you use the id 'x' in the red div? The same id is being used as a class in the second div

Comment: Also, what exactly does 'flex: 0 1 auto' and 'flex: 2 1 auto' does?

Comment: Also, you have used different units 'vh percentage and em'. Is there a rule where to use what unit? Or I mean good practices?

Comment: The x id was just for some JS functionality which I have removed, you can remove that too. I will actually remove it.
The flex proerties for the child elements set how much space they will take each, if there is space provided. IE if one is set to flex: 1 1 auto and the other to 5 1 auto, the other will take 5 times more of the freely available space, if its there, you can see it in effect when you resize/enlarge up the display on codepen.the 2 div x and xyz dont grow equally.

Comment: And good you are pointing out the vh thing, vh and vw just mean viewport height and viewport width, its very useful, but some browsers dont support it, so the fallback would be to use a heigth and width declaration in %, this has to be done before the vh value, as css will always resort to the last line thats supported, means if vh isnt supported, itll be ignored and the previous line will be implemented, changed that to for you

Comment: So, yeah, use vh only as progressive enhancement, always make sure to have a fallback for it with height in %.
As for the em values over pixels, it just grew more convenient on me over time. One is not really better than the other for font declarations, however, for size declaration of elements, I stay away from px values as much as possible.

Comment: You are the man. Thank you very much. I'm going to mark it as the answer. Just one last thing though, the flex properties, child always inherits from its immediate parent, right? So say for example we have set flex direction for the parent div as horizontal but for the extra wrapper we have set it vertically so the header and footer and the inner divs are inheriting from their immediate parent I.e extra wrapper?

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome. You are understanding this very quickly:-)
I was wondering for a while about the same thing and could never find an answer, until I have figured out for myself. See in our example we have the .main div wrapping all, the immediate child divs will be displayed by the rules set to the .main div. Thus, the sidebar and extrawrap are placed horizontaly next to each other. Now, if you declare the extrawrap to display as column, then its child element will be displayed stacked vertically, while the extrawrap is still displayed in a row layout, it inherits this from the .main.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118093/discussion-between-umair-sarfraz-and-damiano-celent).

Comment: Please post the CSS. The Codepen is broken.